# On a finite set, is the discrete topology, only door space?

Tags: general-topology

A topology on $X$ is a door space if every subset of $X$ is either open or closed or both. If $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$, then is the discrete topology only door space?

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: Discrete space is the only topology that contains all the subsets of $X$. As elements of topology all these subsets are open. Any other topology doesn't contains all the subsets of $X$ and therefore can't be door spaces.

Comment: But some of the sets could be closed and not open in a door space.   You have to show that in a four-element door space, every set is in fact open.   (I don't know if this is true.)

Comment: @rk57 ... Perhaps some sets are open but not closed, some are closed but not open, and the rest are both open and closed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathscr{T}$ comprise $\emptyset$ and all subsets of $X$ that contain $a$.  Then $\mathscr{T}$ is a non-discrete topology, and it is a door space, since any set containing $a$ is open and any set not containing $a$ is closed.  $\emptyset$ and $X$ are both, of course.

Comment: perfect! Thank you. Understand my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider e.g. the topology with basis $\{a\},\, \{b\},\, \{c\}$.

Here $\{d\}$ is closed (and not open), and so is every set that contains $d$. The other sets are open.